# Using Beanshell Postprocessor to modify the data extracted from JSON extractor

Tags: json, jmeter

From response,I have extracted the below values using JSON extractor and given name as **data**. But in extracted values i couldn't find double quotes for both variable name and values.

```
{
:   TaxcomputationId=929e1214-cc1a-e711-80c3-000d3ae017ab, 
:   EmployeeId=6524734a-c81a-e711-80c3-000d3ae017ab, 
:   PlanId=609e1214-cc1a-e711-80c3-000d3ae017ab, 
:   AmendmentIndicator=O, 
:   RPEmpId=103622, 
:   Surname=Galvin, 
:   FirstName=Benjaminn, 
:   TFN=433260373, 
:   TerminationDate=16/09/2026, 
:   HomeCountry=null, 
:   HostCountry=null, 
:   StartDateOverseasEmployment=null, 
:   EndDateOverseasEmployment=null, 
:   Assignments=
:   [
:   :   "06\/12\/2006",
:   :   "07\/10\/2010",
:   :   "United States",
:   :   "Australia"
:   ],
:    InboundAssigneeIsNotTemporaryResident=No, 
:   TaxResidencyDuringAssignment=n/a, 
:   DateOfExpiry=24/01/2025, 
:   TaxResidencyAtTP=Non-resident, 
:   ApportionedBasedOnTaxLogic=Yes, 
:   ActualPlanId=1411386-1350, 
:   DOG=/Date(1423094400000)/, 
:   DOV=/Date(1444867200000)/, 
:   DateOfGrant=05/02/2015, 
:   DateOfVest=15/10/2015, 
:   DateOfExercise=22/01/2023, 
:   DateOfSale=31/05/2021, 
:   TaxLogic=Deferred Shares/Performance Rights, 
:   TaxingPoint=Vest, 
:   TaxingDate=15/10/2015, 
:   NoOfESSInterests=52, 
:   FMVAtTPAUD=24.04, 
:   ExercisePriceAUD=0.00, 
:   NoOfSharesWithheldForHypo=1960, 
:   ApportionGrossIncome=Yes, 
:   Comments=, 
:   IncomeNetHypoAUD=-45861.80, 
:   AustralianSourcedIncome=0.00, 
:   ForeignSourcedIncome=-45861.80, 
:   ReportableAmount=0.00, 
:   PercentageOfESSIncomeTaxableInAU=0.00, 
:   IsCalculated=true, 
:   IsLocked=false, 
:   SubmissionStatus=Draft, 
:   IsError=1, 
:   ErrorCells=
:   [
:   :   30,
:   :   32
:   ]
}
```

From the above JSON extractor response, I need to modify the TFN value alone and need to pass this **data** as a parameter to next request. I have tried using beanshell coding it doesnt work. can anyone know how to change those value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest discarding your JSON Path Extractor and completely switch to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) language. The relevant Groovy code which will:

- Perform the extraction of first `result` object
- Change "TFN" attribute value to `foo`
- Store the final JSON into `data` JMeter Variable

will look like:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
def data = json.result.get(0)

data.each {entry ->
    def name = entry.getKey()
    if (name.equals("TFN")) {
        entry.setValue("foo")
    }
}
vars.put("data",new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(data).toPrettyString())
```

References:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 0):

In jp@gc JSON path extractor use $TFN as JSONPATH Expression and store it in variable, then you can pass that variable as parameter in next request

Comment: Could you please more specific? Initially I'm using `$.result[0]` to extract the above values, but the double quotes is missing. From which I have to modify the TFN value as some other 9 digit value and need to pass the entire above JSON as a parameter to next request with the double quotes. Its like from result[2000] I'm extracting the result[0] alone and from which I have to update the TFN number and pass the result[0] value as paramter. i dont know how this will work in Jmeter.

Comment: Using your answer I can able to extract the TFN number, but my need is to give some other values for that TFN